# Any way of getting the comment leader in current grammar in Atom?

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

I'm trying to get the current comment leader for the grammar used in the current file in Atom, to no avail because apparently there's two types of grammar objects, `Grammar`and `TreeSitterGrammar`, so my current method doesn't work. I'm trying the following (I'm not including error checking code, for simplicity):

```
# For TreeSitterGrammars, this work
comment_leader = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().getGrammar().commentStrings.commentStartString

# For Grammar, but this doesn't work because there's no comments property in the ones I've tested
comment_leader = atomatom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().getGrammar().comments.start
```

So, is there any reliable way of getting the comment leader for current grammar using Atom API?

Thanks a lot!